# How to pass pipeline stage variable to makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I am calculating the value of local variable (S_STACK_ID) inside dynamic stage of jenkins pipeline
I need to pass S_STACK_ID variable to makefile so that it could be used in makefile to uniquely identify ECS Stack to be deployed

I have tried below code but it passes blank 'ARGS' to makefile

```
stage('build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def stages = [failFast:true]
                    for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
                            stages["LG ${i}"]={
                                stage ("LG ${i}"){
                                    S_STACK_ID=env.STACK_ID+i
                                    withCredentials([[
                                        sh 'make ARGS="${S_STACK_ID}" build'                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                        parallel stages
                }
            }
        }
```

```
 sh 'make ARGS="myStack" build'  //This correclty passes "myStack" to makefile 

 sh 'make ARGS="${S_STACK_ID}" build' // Passess blank to makefile and not the value of S_STACK_ID which is an issue for me
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to quote the `$` inside the groovy string `'make …'` using `\${S_STACK_ID}` in order for it to be properly passed to the shell, which should than expanded the variable from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked as "" are required for shell commands to interpolate string literals

sh "make clean \"ARGS=${S_STACK_ID}\""